# Subtheorems with alphabetic number

Tags: theorems, counters

I would like to create a list of tasks using LaTeX. Therefore I created a theorem called task. For some tasks I would like to create additional subtheorems using alphabetic numbering. Currently my document is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, british, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{task}{Task}
\newtheorem{subtask}{Task}[task]

\begin{document}

\section{Tasks} % (fold)
\label{sec:number_1}

\begin{task}
    Task 1
\end{task}

\begin{subtask}
    Subtask 1
\end{subtask}

\begin{subtask}
    Subtask 2
\end{subtask}

% section number_1 (end)

\end{document}
```

This produces:

- Task 1.
- Task 1.1.
- Task 1.2.

My aim is an output like:

- Task 1.
- Task 1.a)
- Task 1.b)

and subsubtasks (I do not know whether this word exists or not):

- Task 1.a.a)
- Task 1.a.b)

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to achieve this with `amsthm` because I started with this package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to redefine the way the counter of the subtask or subsubtask is output.
I used your specifiation `\thetask.\alph{subtask})` where `\alph` outputs the letter correspondence to the counter value, say `1->a`

Similarly, `\thesubsubtask` is defined. The commands of `\the...` are always defined, when a new counter is registered, normally, it defaults to `\arabic{counter}`, i.e. arabic number output of the counter value.

**Edit** 06/05/2014: Added the task-theoremstyle to remove the trailing dot of the theorem number, i.e. the 7th. argument to `\newtheoremstyle` must be set to `{}` to remove that dot.

```
\documentclass[11pt, british, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{tasks}{3pt}{3pt}{}{}{\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{tasks}

\newtheorem{task}{Task}
\newtheorem{subtask}{Task}[task]

\newtheorem{subsubtask}{Subtask}[subtask]

% Store for later usage, if needed.
\let\OriginalTheSubTask\thesubtask%
\let\OriginalTheSubSubTask\thesubsubtask%

\renewcommand{\thesubtask}{\thetask.\alph{subtask})}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubtask}{\thetask.\alph{subtask}.\alph{subsubtask})}


\begin{document}

\section{Tasks} % (fold)
\label{sec:number_1}

\begin{task}
    Task 1
\end{task}

\begin{subtask}
    Subtask 1
\end{subtask}

\begin{subsubtask}
    Subsubtask 1
\end{subsubtask}


\begin{subtask}
    Subtask 2
\end{subtask}

\begin{subsubtask}
    Subsubtask 1
\end{subsubtask}


% section number_1 (end)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. There is still a very small discrepancy: the dot at the end of the theorem head. Fortunately this is easily corrected by adding a new theoremstyle and removing the punctation.

Comment: @NickLehmann: I just noted it too: this wrong dot ;-)